# Multi byte store and fetch in Forth - how to implement?

Tags: arrays, forth, gforth

When using large arrays it would be nice to be able to adjust the array for a certain number of bytes per number. Mostly I want fast routines to read such adjusted multi byte numbers to singles on the stack and conversely to store singles in the array adjusted for a certain number of bytes. In a 64 bit system there is a need for other single number arrays than one byte (c@ c!) and eight bytes (@ !).

So how to implement

```
cs@ ( ad b -- n )
cs! ( n ad b -- )
```

where b is the number of bytes. The word cs! seems to work as

```
: cs! ( n ad b -- )  >r sp@ cell+ swap r> cmove drop ;
```

but how about cs@ and how to do it in pure ANS Forth without sp@ or similar words?

Comment: Note that `CS` stands for Control-Flow Stack operations, like`cs-roll` etc, see [The optional Programming-Tools word set](http://www.forth200x.org/documents/html/tools.html). So usage `cs` suffix for other semantics may confuse.

Comment: Yes, it felt familiar but I didn't thought about that. Better names are perhaps mb@ and mb!

Comment: Must the expression `addr @` give the same result as `addr 8 mb@` in case of cell size is 64 bits? I mean that `cmove` may lead to different result in such case. Also note that in general case byte order may differ in memory and on stack.

Comment: No, that's not necessary. It just have to work for 2-7 bytes, no matter how. Speed is the interesting thing.

Comment: @ruvim: 2-7 bytes in 64 bit systems and 2-3 bytes in 32 bit systems would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

The Forth200*x* committee has put quite some time into developing a [Memory Access](http://www.forth200x.org/memory-2010-06-26.txt) wordset that would suite.  We have not included it into the standard thus far due to its size.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11465846)

Comment: If you actually follow the link and read the article you will find it
not only provides a discussion on the difficulty of providing such
words but also provides a definition of a collection of 22 words that
make this easer to do, along with the unit tests to validate the
words are working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The compatible way is to use `C@` and bitwise operations. To use the same byte order in memory as Forth system there is need to detect endianness and compile the suitable versions of the certain definitions.

```
\ These definitions use little-endian format in memory.
\ Assumption: char size and address unit size equal to 1 octet.

: MB! ( x addr u -- )
  ROT >R  OVER +  SWAP
  BEGIN  2DUP U>  WHILE  R> DUP 8 RSHIFT >R OVER C! 1+ REPEAT
  2DROP RDROP
;
: MB@ ( addr u -- x )
  0 >R  OVER +
  BEGIN  2DUP U<  WHILE  1- DUP C@ R> 8 LSHIFT OR >R  REPEAT
  2DROP R>
;
```

For higher performance it could be better to use implementation specific features (including `W@`, `T@`, `Q@`, `SP@`, etc) or even inline Forth-assembler.

Note that a straightforward definition via `DO` loop usually has worse performance (depends on optimizer; 10% in SP-Forth/4.21). The code for reference:

```
: MB! ( x addr u -- )
  OVER + SWAP ?DO DUP I C! 8 RSHIFT LOOP DROP
;
: MB@ ( addr u -- x )
  DUP 0= IF NIP EXIT THEN
  0 -ROT
  1- OVER + DO 8 LSHIFT I C@ OR -1 +LOOP
;
```

We can't use `?DO` in the second case because of decreasing the loop index and [`+LOOP` semantics](http://forth.sourceforge.net/std/dpans/dpans6.htm#6.1.0140): it leaves circle when the index crosses "the boundary between the loop **limit minus one** and the loop limit".

Comment: What is the idea of not using do-loop?

Comment: @Lehs the idea of not using do-loop is performance — I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
\ little-endian (eg. pc, android)
: mb! ( n ad i -- )  2>r here ! here 2r> cmove ;
: mb@ ( ad i -- n )  here 0 over ! swap cmove here @ ;

\ big-endian (eg. mac)
: mb! ( n ad i -- )  2>r here ! here cell + r@ - 2r> cmove ;
: mb@ ( ad i -- n )  here 0 over ! cell + over - swap cmove here @ ;

\ little-endian test
1 here ! here c@ negate .
```

Of course HERE could be any one cell buffer.

Thanks ruvim for parsing the process forward!

Comment: Nice idea — short solution! Although, by my tests, the performance of this solution worse than the solution with do-loop. Also note that these definitions will work wrong in case of **big-endian**. Also, `mb@` should erase buffer before move data.

Comment: @ruvim: you are right. Here should be cleared. What is big-endian?

Comment: It is better to don't use `HERE` at all to avoid clashes, and use per-thread buffer or buffer on return stack. Regarding big-endian see [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: @ruvim, I'm not sure you are right about the big-endian. The same pattern that is stored will also be fetched, independent of arithmetic convensions. Or?

Comment: With big-endian `0x332211 addr 3 mb!` will do: `0x332211 HERE ! ( 00 33 22 11 is written in mem) HERE addr 3 CMOVE ( 00 33 22 is written in mem)`. And byte 11 is lost.

Comment: @ruvim, yes I must think it over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96447/discussion-between-ruvim-and-lehs).